# How to select element by 'role' attribute and filter by class with vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

Markup:

```
<ul>
  <li role="presentation" class="active">
    <a href="#1" aria-controls="1" role="tab">How to Install for iPad</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#2" aria-controls="2" role="tab">How to Install for Mac</a>
  </li>
  <li role="presentation">
    <a href="#3" aria-controls="3" role="tab">How to Install for PC</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I use ***document.querySelectorAll('[role="presentation"]');***  the result is array 
*[li.active,li,li]*

How can I remove .active class and attach it to any other of these li with plain JS w/o JQuery the more simplest way?

Comment: Please include a [mcve] of what you've tried. What you have here is a work-order not a question.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Your question makes it sound like you want to randomly move the `.active` class onto any of the other `li` elements, but I'm guessing that isn't what you actually want?

Comment: @JamesDonnelly , thanks for your reply! My goal is to turn-off .active from the first li and set it up to the last li element.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Try this:

```
// remove active class from all elements
document.querySelectorAll('[role="presentation"]').forEach(function (el){
el.classList.remove("active");
});

// add class 'active' to last element
document.querySelectorAll('[role="presentation"]:last-of-type')[0].classList.add("active")
```

Notes:

- 'classList' will not work in IE9;
- I think you have to modify adding class row, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var ele = document.querySelectorAll('[role="presentation"]');
ele[0].classList.remove("active"); //Remove active class for first element
ele[ele.length- 1].classList.add("active"); //Apply active class for last element
console.log(ele)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var eleLi = document.querySelectorAll('[role="presentation"]');  
for (var i = 0; i < eleLi.length; i++) {
    //remove class active
    eleLi[i].classList.remove('active');
}

//x is an index of li that you want to add the class. Such as 0,1,2
var x = eleLi.length - 1;

//add class active
eleLi[x].classList.add('active');
```