# Manipulate content # for all div elements (with role="tabpanel") - style="display: none;" to display: block;

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, dom

How to manipulate a website to change all
div elements (with role="tabpanel") - style="display: none;" to style="display: block;"

- via class="accordionItemContent" could be possible as well

I would like to see the whole page/div elements with total content (so it doesn't matter is the manipulation is via JS or CSS .. or jquery)

```
<div class="accordionItemContent accordion ui-reset widget uibottom" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;"></div>
```

Because the page is behind a login probably a change via site inspect/console would be one way to go.

---

Update

I have been to fast when writing about "display"

- if "block" it only shows a frame without content

I saw that there is another main difference in the element shown vs all other hidden once:

```
<h1 class="uiaccordion" role="tab" a-exp="false" a-sel="false" tabindex="-1"><a href="#" id="manage_content_11_ac" tabindex="-1"></div>
<h1 class="uiaccordion" role="tab" a-exp="true"  a-sel="true"  tabindex="0"> <a href="#" id="manage_content_12_ac" tabindex="-1"></div>
```

-> How to see/activate the content as well?

Comment: Here's something to get your Javascript code started. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46648761/how-to-select-element-by-role-attribute-and-filter-by-class-with-vanilla-js

Comment: It looks like the author of that page is in troubles, if they're hiding authored content from unauthored visitors just with CSS ...

Comment: the solutions show the frame [without content] (like asked in the original question). How to activate the content as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this in console

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div.accordionItemContent.accordion.ui-reset.widget.uibottom[role="tabpanel"]').forEach(e => {
   e.style.display = "block";
});
```

Edited for edited question, only using class `accordionItemContent`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div.accordionItemContent[role="tabpanel"]').forEach(e => {
   e.style.display = "block";
});
```

To change the other attributes as mentioned in the update:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('div.accordionItemContent[role="tabpanel"]').forEach(e => {
   e.style.display = "block";
   e.setAttribute(“tabindex”, 0) // Use this syntax to change all effected attributes
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery...

```
$("div[role='tabpanel']").show();
```

or...

```
$('.accordionItemContent').show();
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be creating a generic CSS class to hide elements and add/remove it to the element(s) you want to hide/show:

```js
function showDivs() {
  document.querySelectorAll('[role=tabpanel]').forEach(elem => elem.classList.remove('hide'));
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showDivs()">show hidden DIVs</button>

<div class="accordionItemContent accordion ui-reset widget uibottom hide" role="tabpanel">DIV1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit consecutor amet</div>
<div class="accordionItemContent accordion ui-reset widget uibottom hide" role="tabpanel">DIV2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit consecutor amet</div>
<div class="accordionItemContent accordion ui-reset widget uibottom hide" role="tabpanel">DIV3: Lorem ipsum dolor sit consecutor amet</div>
```

If you prefer to stick with inline CSS, instead, you can modify the code above in this way:

```js
function showDivs() {
  document.querySelectorAll('[role=tabpanel]').forEach(elem => {
    elem.style.display = 'block';
    /*
     * NOTE: if the inline style contains only the display property,
     * you could even entirely remove it:
     * 
     *   elem.removeAttribute('style');
     */    
  });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showDivs()">show hidden DIVs</button>

<div class="accordionItemContent accordion ui-reset widget uibottom" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;">DIV1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit consecutor amet</div>
<div class="accordionItemContent accordion ui-reset widget uibottom" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;">DIV2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit consecutor amet</div>
<div class="accordionItemContent accordion ui-reset widget uibottom" role="tabpanel" style="display: none;">DIV3: Lorem ipsum dolor sit consecutor amet</div>
```